# python timer trigger errors no job functions found

Tags: python, azure-functions, timer-trigger

I have created an azure timer trigger function using python, IDE as VSCode. My project folder structure is as shown below.
[image]

As you can see on the "Terminal" it is giving me an error saying "No job functions found". This is because my "Dockerfile" and "requirements.txt" are inside folder "setup" which is inside folder(TimerTrigger1). If these 2 files are at the project root it works fine. However I need a folder structure similar to the one shown in the screen shot above. As I would end up creating multiple functions each in a separate folder like the one shown in the screenshot(TimerTrigger1)

Please share your thoughts. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

First, the structure of the function app is impossible to change.

Second, those configuration files do not affect your creation of multiple functions. Just press F1 and select create new function.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for replying. you mean to say I can't put "requirements.txt" and "Dockerfile" inside folder "setup". What if I have different "requirements.txt" and "Dockerfile" for each of my function?

Comment: @VijayAnde Why do you want each function to have its own requirements.txt? This file itself installs the package for the entire function app.

Comment: I want to have docker image for each of the function in my function app. so, I want to have separate requirements.txt and Dockerfile for each function. so that requirements-1.txt, dockerfile-1 belong to function-1 and so on for others

Comment: hi Bowman, is there a way to have a folder structure the way I have mentioned in my original post? I mean having "Docker file" and "requirements.txt" inside my "TimerTrigger1" function, similarly for the other functions?